# Is an object-type variable a reference, and that's it? or can it also be a reference to a reference?

Tags: c#, memory-management, reference, boxing, object-type

Hi there I've got a fast question ( closed-ended question ) I faced while studying boxing and unboxing concept in C#:

The variable of "object" type, which is a reference type variable, can take   a copy of value type variable or of a reference type variable.

Let's consider an object type variable declared in the stack.

Firstly, it's taking a copy of a value type variable:

```
int a;
object b = a;
```

And secondly it's taking a copy of a reference type variable:

```
string c;
object d = c;
```

Now the question here is: Compared to the first object-type variable ( object b ) which is represented in the memory by a reference in the stack with the data of int-type in the heap, the second object-type variable ( object d ) would it have a reference in the stack to  the data of string text in the heap or rather it would have a reference in the stack to another reference in the heap to the data of string text?

In other words does:

```
string X = "ABC";
```

equals:

```
object Y = "ABC";
```

or either:

```
object Z = X;
```

or not

.........

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Thank you Hossein for editing.

Comment: No need for thanks, editing is a usual task in StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference types are not boxed. You would be assigning the reference from one variable to another. The only copying that happens is the reference (usually implemented as a pointer). The data in the object is not copied, but remains where it is.

You are more or less correct with regards to value types.

I'd advise you not to think about the heap and the stack. They are implementation details. Moreover, it's not true that value types always live on the stack. Instead, you should think about it in terms of copy semantics. Value types are always copied, and reference types are not. That's all there is to it.

EDIT: I reread your question to try to understand what you were really asking, so I can answer more clearly.

`X` is a local variable of type `string` that contains a reference to an object of type `string`. `Y` is a local variable of type `object` that contains a reference to an object of type `string`. This is allowed because `string` derives from `object` and a variable may safely contain a reference to an object of its own type, or any type from which that type derives (either class or interface). `Z` is a local variable of type `object` which contains a reference to an object of type `string`. It is functionally the same as `X`. You simply have two variables that contain a reference to the same object. There is no additional referencing happening.

I think you may be confused because you might be thinking that the creation of the reference happens during assignment. All assignment does is copy the reference (for reference types) and copy the value (for value types). You can only create a reference to a reference with the `ref` keyword in a method parameter.

There's an added wrinkle with string literals. They are stored in a global table, one entry per unique string literal. If you assign the same string literal to two variables, they will both point to (i.e., reference) the same entry in that global table. This is different from using `new` twice, but is similar to initializing two `int` variables with the same value, semantically.

Comment: Thank you for your response siride, indeed

actually I know that a value type is not always in the stack, if it's a member of instantiated object, or it was a static class member, it will live in the heap, in fact I haven't said the opposite at all in the question,

Now back to the answer your provided, since no boxing for reference types, does that mean, in my question the variables X, Y , and Z are just the same in memory management, all with a single reference in the stack with the data in the heap ( with Z and X sharing the same reference, while Y has its unique reference )?

Comment: Thank you for reconsidering the question, that's nice from you I appreciate it. And the answer is just perfect for me, thank you brother. Actually I know that the reference is created rather while declaring the variable and not during assigning it to a value ( or to an address where the value reside I guess ),

Comment: But what confused me is my lack of knowledge of that a reference will not be boxed but rather copied quite simply like copying any reference type variable and here the object-type variable is no unique at all. The rest of your answer I feel I'll go back to it when my level of knowledge grow enough. Thank you again for clarification.

Comment: @Physician: ahh, I think I understand your issue. Boxing is a special operation that is *only* used for value types when they need to be passed by reference because they are being stored in a variable that has a reference type. Reference types have no equivalent operation.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is copied by value when boxing. `b` refers to the boxed value of `a`. `a` and `b` are independent.

The same is true for the second example, but there is no boxing. The reference is copied.

Assignment in C# *always* copies the value or reference. It never creates a reference to a storage location.

> would it have a reference in the stack to the data of string text in the heap or rather it would have a reference in the stack to another reference in the heap to the data of string text

None of that. Object references in C# always point to an object, not to another reference. There is no such thing as a chain of references.

Comment: Thank you usr for your response, the first quote contain an error I made unintentionally that seems to change the meaning, I corrected it in the question, Sorry for that.

Comment: OK, is your question answered?

Comment: Yeah, it's a quite relevant and accurate explanation, however mr sirirde's answer above is more detailed so that it helped me little more to understand so I accepted it as an answer to my question, thanks for your effort brother